# Refresh SAS Token for Azure Blob Storage

Tags: angular, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a video file (mp4) saved in Azure Bob storage. I am accessing this video file via a SAS Token. The SAS Token expires in 45 seconds. Suppose the video is 5 minutes, the video displayed will only play for 45 seconds and halt.

What I want to do is to get a new SAS Token every 45 seconds and the video will play continuously without halting. How can I alter my code so it displays the video continuously ?

Note: The code I have will only play the video for 45 seconds and then halts. I am using Angular.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getVideoURL ();
}


  getVideoURL () : Observable <string>
  {
      return this.httpClient.get<string>('https://url.com/getsastoken', { responseType: "json"})
      .pipe(map (
        (data: string) =>
        {
          this.sasTOken = data;
          this.urlOfVideo = 'https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/app.mp4?'+ this.sasTOken;
        }
      ));
  }
```

HTML

```
            <video oncontextmenu="return false;"  id="vid1" class="amp-default-skin" controlsList="nodownload" autoplay controls width="640" height="400" poster="poster.jpg" data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}'>
                <source src={{urlOfVideo}} >
            </video>
```

Comment: you cannot renew a SAS token. you have to generate a new one.

Comment: @silent Yes. That's what I have mentioned in my post. I need to get a new SASToken every 45seconds. How can I alter my code to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot alter an SAS, and I doubt you could easily modify your code to frequently change the SAS token on your URI.

However: You *can* create a *Stored Access Policy* (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/define-stored-access-policy)). You will find this option in the portal, while viewing the container storing your video (Access Policies cannot be set on an individual blob; rather, they are set on a specific container). For video viewing, you should set this to only have Read permission.

You may then set a start/stop time on the policy (I haven't tried it with a 45-second window, but I suspect this will work). Once this is set up, you may generate an SAS based on the policy. At this point, adding the SAS to your video's URI will grant an end-user ability to view/stream your video content, until the expiration time.

Independent of the SAS, you may edit (or delete) the Access Policy which the SAS is based on. So... in your case, you can periodically extend the end date of your policy (thereby keeping the SAS-based URI valid). Just note that it takes upwards of 30 seconds for any change to take effect. Also note that the policy would apply to all blobs within a given container.

I mentioned the portal, so that you can try out policies/SAS, but this is all doable via SDK calls as well ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-stored-access-policy-define-dotnet?tabs=dotnet) is documentation for the .NET SDK, for example).

Comment: I actually want to receive a *New* SASToken and not extend. This is to prevent users from unauthorized Download of the video file. So that's why I have a 45 second expiration time. So every 45 seconds I want to New SAS Token so it'll make it hard for the hacker to download content. I want to know how I could generate a Token every 45 seconds ? Is it by having a timer and shooting out a request when it reaches 40 seconds ? Also will the video continuously play without lagging ?

Comment: I can't imagine that scheme would ever work, as the client would need to re-establish a connection every 45 seconds. Plus, considering you could have clock-drift, which could result in occasional stream interruptions (meaning, unlikely to ever be able to have a smooth streaming experience). My solution allows you to update the policy, exactly as you're talking about, without bothering the client. And if the policy isn't updated... the SAS expires right along with the policy.

Comment: tl;dr you're trying to do something SAS isn't meant for.

Comment: My objective is to prevent users from copying/downloading videos. What might be a good approach to deal with this ? Help :( This is why I am expiring the SAS token every 45 seconds to make it impossible for a user to download the video. By updating the Policy the user will still be able to download the content. Is there any workarounds ?

Comment: You're really asking a broad question now (and Stack Overflow comments really aren't the place for discussion or additional questions). Maybe look into ways of embedding videos in your site? But that isn't related to your original question, which has been answered (both in comments under the question, and here in my answer)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me understand about SAS tokens and using access policies. I will also investigate on embedding videos, that will hide the URL or make it unable to download.